# Thread safe iteration in Groovy

Tags: multithreading, loops, groovy, thread-safety

I'm trying to figure out if there is a 'groovier' way to iterate thread safe in Groovy than the [usual way in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) iterating a `Collections.synchronizedList` inside a synchronized block, but I've found no reference to this issue (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping).

Are `each` and `eachWithIndex` thread-safe? If not, is there an easy way to iterate thread-safe already provided by Groovy? Or should I use the old Java way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea is that every thread will iterate the list without causing any trouble to the others. I could use the typical mechanisms in Java, but my question is if there is something in Groovy that could do the trick easily like let's say 'eachSynchronized'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy's each uses iterators underneath (see the each method in [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java)).  As such, no, they would not be thread-safe in and of themselves.  But you could obviously still use them within a synchronized block.  You might also be interested in the [@Synchronized](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Synchronized.html) AST transformation.